# Search the set of the same character that was used

Tags: powershell

I would like to determine via a search whether a character more often or less than a defined number. For example

ABC_2019_02_01_blabla_05.pdf <- right

ABC_DEF_192_1111_oaoaoa.pdf -false

For me, the decisive factor is the **amount of "_" used**. For example, only 5 times the character _ may have been used.

```
Get-ChildItem -af -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch '_*_*_*_*_' } | % { $_.FullName }
```

Don't work for that.

I would like to determine via a search whether a character more often or less than a defined number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.split` method as a way to count the number of instance of a specific character.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -af -recurse
$Files | Where-Object {$_.Name.Split('_').Length-1 -gt 5}
```

Alternatively...

```
# Using regex... careful with special characters
$Files | Where-Object { [regex]::matches($_.Name, "_").count -gt 5}

# Grouping the char array representation of the string
$Files | Where-Object { ($_.Name.ToCharArray() | Group-Object | Where-Object Name -eq '_').Count -gt 5 }
```

And just for fun...

If you want both the valid items and invalid ones into a separate array, you can achieve that via the `.where` method, which accept an additional parameter to further define the search.

Using that sample below, invalid items (more than 5 times the `_` character) will end up in the first array (`$Invalid`) while the valid items (the ones that were not picked up by our condition) will end up in the second array `$Valid` ([reference](https://ss64.com/ps/where-method.html))

```
$Invalid,$Valid = $Files.Where({$_.Name.Split('_').Length-1 -gt 5},'split')
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Sage Pourpre's helpful solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71421071/45375):

Two more ways to **count the number of occurrences of a given character in a string**:

```
# -> 5, 4
@{ Name = 'ABC_2019_02_01_blabla_05.pdf' },
@{ Name = 'ABC_DEF_192_1111_oaoaoa.pdf' } | 
  ForEach-Object {
    ($_.Name.ToCharArray() -eq '_').Count
  }
```

This relies on the [`-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) operator acting as a *filter* when the LHS is an *array*: in effect, it returns the subarray of characters that are `_`, whose element count is therefore the number of `_` chars. in the input.

```
# -> 5, 4
@{ Name = 'ABC_2019_02_01_blabla_05.pdf' }, # Sample input
@{ Name = 'ABC_DEF_192_1111_oaoaoa.pdf' } | 
  ForEach-Object {
    ($_.Name -replace '[^_]').Length
  }
```

This relies on using the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator for removing all characters *other than* `_` (`[^_]`) from the input string, which leaves a string composed only of the `_` chars., whose length is therefore the number of `_` chars. in the input.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your attempt, if corrected, has the potential to **perform additional validation**, such as requiring that `_` characters be surrounded by at least one *other* character, such that, say, `'a_b_c_d_e_f.pdf'` is valid, but `'abcdef_____.pdf'` is not.

```
# -> $true, $false, $false
@{ Name = 'ABC_2019_02_01_blabla_05.pdf' }, # OK
@{ Name = 'abcdef_____.pdf' }, # Correct number of "_", but in the wrong places
@{ Name = 'ABC_DEF_192_1111_oaoaoa.pdf' } | # Not enough "_"
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name -match '^([^_]+_){5}[^_]+$'
  }
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/799vw7/1).